# How can I deny a request with a specific url encoded character?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm having problems with a site being exploited, and I have tried many ways to solve this, but I'm missing some skills to get it done.

The issue is I need to deny POST requests to "/%21/Form/create" while accepting POST requests to "/!/Form/create".

I have tried:

```
location = /%21/Form/create {
deny all;
}
```

```
location ~ ^/%21.*/ {
deny all;
}
```

without any luck. I would really appreciate some help solving this.

Comment: The percent encoded character is decoded before `location` processes the URL, try: `location = /!/Form/create { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith The thing is I need /!/Form/create to still work ;( So I was hoping there was a way to separate them, but if I understand you correctly it is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same URL - but if your server is receiving both forms of request - and you need to differentiate between them - you can use `$request_uri` to view the request as it was originally received.

The variable can be tested using an `if` block.

```
if ($request_uri = /%21/Form/create) { return 403; }
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for providing me with this solution. It worked perfect!